# PropertySource not working in DispatcherServletInitializer

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I have a servlet extends `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`, in which I need to read an external property file using `@PropertySource` as below. However, it returns `NullPointerException`.
If I do it on other bean class then it works fine and can successfully read the external property file.

What I just wanted to have is getting a key-value pair from external file when I startup the servlet. I also tried `ResourceLoader` but somehow still not working...

I spent a whole day and googled many blogs but still no findings on how to resolve it.
Could anyone please give me some clues?

Many thanks!

**myenv.properties**

```
system.env=DEV
```

**WebAppInitializer.java**

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "file:C:\\myenv.properties")
public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebAppInitializer.class);

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        super.onStartup(servletContext);

        String systemEnv = env.getProperty("system.env");
        LOGGER.info("systemEnv: {}", systemEnv);
        servletContext.setInitParameter("spring.profiles.active", systemEnv );
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { ...... };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { ...... };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }
}
```

Comment: It will never work. The `@Propertysource` is processed as part of loading the application context. You are bootstrapping the servlet etc. which is way before that point. If you want to read the file you will have to do that manually (no autowiring either!).

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you for your help. I resolved it by manually reading the file as you suggested. Cheers.